# NodeJs using Nodemailer to spoof sender/from email aadress for gmail

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, gmail, nodemailer

Is it possible/How to send an email through nodemailer with a "dynamic" sender email?
(smtp)

For example:

In Gmail I would receive a new email that was sent from  121llkkjsdf@mytestsite.com

Where "121llkkjsdf" is a randomly generated string
and mytestsite.com is where I have nodemailer setup.

```
    var message = { 
    // sender info
    from: '121llkkjsdf <121llkkjsdf@mytestsite.com>',

    // Comma separated list of recipients
    to: '<someone@somewhere.com>',

    // Subject of the message
    subject: '', //

    // plaintext body
    text: '',

    // HTML body
    html: ''
    };
```

If i only give nodemailer this above object, it still uses the smtp account sender email.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass from property a random variable and define a function that generates your string:

```
var random_string = function () {
  // your random string code goes here
};

var message = {
  from: random_string,
  to: '<someone@somewhere.com>',
  // ...
}
```

Comment: My problem is that i use nodemailer with SMTP (smtp account) and gmail still receives email from that smtp account not from my defined adress